# querying rdf triples

Tags: rdf, sparql, owl, virtuoso

How can I write sparql query where I can compare the variables (?a, ?b), if I have the following eg? (something's wrong with this eg?):

```
<ont:XXXXX rdf:about="http://www.myOntDomain#C">
   <ro:part_of rdf:resource="http://www.myOntDomain#A">
   <ro:part_of rdf:resource="http://www.myOntDomain#B">
</ont:XXXXX>
```

This doesn't give me what I want:

```
select ?s ?a ?b
where {
   ?s a ont:XXXXX; ro:part_of ?a; ro:part_of ?b .
   filter(str(?a) = "http://www.myOntDomain#A" && str(?b) = "http://www.myOntDomain#B")
}
```

I want:

```
http://www.myOntDomain#C http://www.myOntDomain#A http://www.myOntDomain#B
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Your question, or rather your intent, is rather unclear because the only unknown in your query as you have written it is `:C`. You already know the identities of `:A` and `:B`, because you're quoting their URI's *in the query itself*.

I can think of two interpretations of what you're trying to do:

First, you just want to know the `?s` which is an `ont:XXXXX` and has `part_of` `:A` and `:B` :

```
select ?s where {
    ?s a ont:XXXXX ;
       ro:part_of <http://www.myOntDomain#A> ;
       ro:part_of <http://www.myOntDomain#B>
}
```

Alternatively, you want to know the `?s` which is an `ont:XXXXX` and which has (at least) two distinct parts:

```
select ?s ?a ?b where {
    ?s a ont:XXXXX ;
       ro:part_of ?a, ?b
       FILTER (?a != ?b)
}
```

If neither of these match what you're actually trying to do, you'll need to make the question clearer.